# performance issue on left join with subquery to find out the latest date

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

```
SELECT m.*, pc.call_date                     
                    FROM messages m
                    LEFT JOIN customers c ON m.device_user_id = c.device_user_id
                    LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON pc.id = (
                        SELECT MAX(pc2.id)
                        FROM phone_call pc2
                        WHERE pc2.device_user_id = c.device_user_id OR pc2.customer_id = c.customer_id
                    )
```

The issue with the above is the left join phone_call table to find out the latest phone call made for each record. phone_call table has GBs of data. With left join phone_call, it takes more than 30 secs to return data. without it less than a sec. so that table is the issue. is there a better way to achieve the same result as the above query?

Comment: Code questions require a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX subquery can't use an index due to the OR condition. Split this subquery into two - one for each condition - and take the highest result using `GREATEST()`:

```
SELECT m.*, pc.call_date                     
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN customers c ON m.device_user_id = c.device_user_id
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON pc.id = GREATEST((
  SELECT MAX(pc2.id)
  FROM phone_call pc2
  WHERE pc2.device_user_id = c.device_user_id
), (
  SELECT MAX(pc2.id)
  FROM phone_call pc2
  WHERE pc2.customer_id = c.customer_id
))
```

Each subquery will need it's own index - which are

```
phone_call(device_user_id, id)
phone_call(customer_id, id)
```

If `phone_call.id` is the primary key and the table is using *InnoDB*, then you can omnit it from the index, since it will be appended implicitly.

Since one of the subqueries might return `NULL` you should use `COALESCE()` with a  number smaller than any existing id. If `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` then `0` should be fine:

```
SELECT m.*, pc.call_date                     
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN customers c ON m.device_user_id = c.device_user_id
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON pc.id = GREATEST(
  COALESCE((
    SELECT MAX(pc2.id)
    FROM phone_call pc2
    WHERE pc2.device_user_id = c.device_user_id
  ), 0), 
  COALESCE((
    SELECT MAX(pc2.id)
    FROM phone_call pc2
    WHERE pc2.customer_id = c.customer_id
  ), 0)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you phrased the query looks good to me for MySQL 5.7. But the `OR` in the subquery is a performance killer.

I would recommend the following index, so the correlated subquery executed quickly:

```
phone_call(device_user_id, customer_id, id)
```

You might try and switch the first two columns in the index to see if one version or another has better effect.

Another thing you *could try* is change the subquery to use a sort and a row limiting clause rather than aggregation (with the same above index in place). There is guarantee it will improve things, but it is worth trying:

```
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON pc.id = (
    SELECT pc2.id
    FROM phone_call pc2
    WHERE 
        pc2.device_user_id = c.device_user_id 
        OR pc2.customer_id = c.customer_id
    ORDER BY pc2.id
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Finally, another idea is to split the subquery into two to  avoid the `OR`:

```
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON pc.id = (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(pc2.id)
        FROM phone_call pc2
        WHERE pc2.device_user_id = c.device_user_id 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MAX(pc3.id)
        FROM phone_call pc3
        WHERE pc3.customer_id = c.customer_id
    ) t
)
```

Or without intermediate aggregation:

```
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON pc.id = (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM (
        SELECT pc2.id
        FROM phone_call pc2
        WHERE pc2.device_user_id = c.device_user_id 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pc3.id
        FROM phone_call pc3
        WHERE pc3.customer_id = c.customer_id
    ) t
)
```

For the last two queries, you would need two indexes:

```
phone_call(device_user_id, id)
phone_call(customer_id, id)
```

---

**EDIT**

The above solutions using `union all` require MySQL 8.0 - in earlier versions, they fail because the subqueries are too deeply nested to reference columns from the outer query. So, another alternative is `IN`:

```
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON pc.id IN (
    SELECT pc2.id
    FROM phone_call pc2
    WHERE pc2.device_user_id = c.device_user_id 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT pc3.id
    FROM phone_call pc3
    WHERE pc3.customer_id = c.customer_id
)
```

This can also be phase with `EXISTS` - which I like better, because the predicates explicitly match the indexes definition, so it should be an easy decision for MySQL to use them:

```
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM phone_call pc2
    WHERE pc2.device_user_id = c.device_user_id AND pc2.id = pc.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    FROM phone_call pc3
    WHERE pc3.customer_id = c.customer_id AND pc3.id = pc.id
)
```

Again, this works under the assumption that you have the two following, multicolumn indexes:

```
phone_call(device_user_id, id)
phone_call(customer_id, id)
```

You can create the indexes as follow:

```
create index idx_phone_call_device_user on phone_call(device_user_id, id);
create index idx_phone_call_customer    on phone_call(customer_id, id);
```

Comment: @SO-user: do you have a *compound* index on the three columns, or an index on each column?

Comment: index on each column. and I've tried that order by id desc query already. no diff. I'll try your other two queries. those are some nice ideas.

Comment: @SO-user: I meant a multi column index. An index on each column won’t help.

Comment: Okay. I'll look into that and get back. Have not tried it before.

Comment: in the last two queries, c.device_user_id is not recognised since we use it inside a subquery of another.

Comment: @SO-user: it seems this syntax only works on MySQL 8.0, not in earlier versions. I edited my answer with another solution for earlier versions. Please check.

Comment: in the latest query of yours, we have to choose the lastest id after the union. @GMB

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will probably not like this answer, but, if this is going to be an important data and a frequent query, I would put `last_call_date` as a field in customer's table.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not allowed to do that as it affects past data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is related to [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem there are several ways to get the latest record as per your grouping criteria. One of them is using self joins and you could rewrite your query as

```
SELECT  m.*,
        pc.call_date                     
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN customers c ON m.device_user_id = c.device_user_id
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc ON pc.device_user_id = c.device_user_id OR pc.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN phone_call pc2 ON (
    (pc.device_user_id = pc2.device_user_id OR pc.customer_id = pc2.customer_id) AND pc1.call_date < pc2.call_date
)
WHERE pc2.call_date IS NULL
```

In above query where clause is important to filter out rows with older date, You will also need to add a composite index on `phone_call` table

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON phone_call(device_user_id,customer_id,call_date);
```

> The query optimizer cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not form a [leftmost prefix](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-composite-index) of the index.

Moreover please execute [EXPLAIN PLAN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) for your query to see performance related issues and to make sure that right indexes are being used.

[Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/853360)